# ¿Cómo transformar de una sola vez varias columnas numéricas de un marco de datos en categorías?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, categorical

Tengo una dataframe `df` con numeros entre 1 y 7 y me gustaria transformar los en catagorias (`neg` si esta <3, `pos` si esta >5 y `neut` sino):

```
    A       B       C       D       E
0   3.75    3.50    4.00    4.75    3.00
1   4.75    5.25    3.75    5.50    2.00
2   3.25    4.00    3.75    4.00    5.50
3   2.75    4.00    4.00    4.00    2.75
```

Entonces intenté:

```
for col in columns:
    for _, row in df[col].iterrows():
        if row<3:
            df.iloc[i,row] = "neg"
        elif row >5:
            df.iloc[i,row] = "pos"
        else:
            df.iloc[i,row] = "neut"
```

Pero obtengo:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-71393cdf0d1e> in <module>
      2 
      3 for col in columns:
----> 4     for _, row in df[col].iterrows():
      5         if row<3:
      6             df.iloc[i,row] = "neg"

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5273                 return self[name]
-> 5274             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5275 
   5276     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'
```

Intenté tambien:

```
df.loc[df['A','B', 'C', 'D','E'] > 5, ['A','B', 'C', 'D','E']] = "pos"
```

Pero me devuelvé:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: ('Openess', 'Conscientiousness', 'Extraversion', 'Agreeableness', 'Neuroticism')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-132-bd0104cc9380> in <module>
     11 #             df.iloc[i,row] = "neut"
     12 
---> 13 df.loc[df['Openess','Conscientiousness', 'Extraversion', 'Agreeableness','Neuroticism'] > 5, ['Openess','Conscientiousness', 'Extraversion', 'Agreeableness','Neuroticism']] = "pos"

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2801             if is_integer(indexer):
   2802                 indexer = [indexer]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: ('Openess', 'Conscientiousness', 'Extraversion', 'Agreeableness', 'Neuroticism')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías simplemente usar el tipo [`Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalDtype.html#pandas.CategoricalDtype) para tus columnas. PAra segmentar por los intervalos deseados puedes usar [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
import io
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


data = io.StringIO("""     
   A       B       C       D       E
3.75    3.50    4.00    4.75    3.00
3.45    5.25    3.75    5.50    2.00
3.25    4.00    3.75    4.00    5.50
2.75    4.00    4.00    4.00    2.75
""")


df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\s+")
```

> ```
> >>> df
>       A     B     C     D     E
> 0  3.75  3.50  4.00  4.75  3.00
> 1  3.45  5.25  3.75  5.50  2.00
> 2  3.25  4.00  3.75  4.00  5.50
> 3  2.75  4.00  4.00  4.00  2.75
> ```

```
df = pd.cut(df.stack(),
            (-np.inf, 2.99, 5, np.inf),
            labels=('neg', 'neut', 'pos')
            ).unstack()
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>       A     B     C     D     E
> 0  neut  neut  neut  neut  neut
> 1  neut   pos  neut   pos   neg
> 2  neut  neut  neut  neut   pos
> 3   neg  neut  neut  neut   neg
> ```

---

### Edición

Si solo se quiere pasar a categóricas ciertas columnas del DataFrame basta con usar `loc` para seleccionar las deseadas y reasignarles el nuevo valor:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import numpy as np



data = io.StringIO("""     
   A       B       C       D       E
3.75    3.50    4.00    4.75    3.00 
3.45    5.25    3.75    5.50    2.00    
3.25    4.00    3.75    4.00    5.50
2.75    4.00    4.00    4.00    2.75
""")

import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\s+")

df.loc[:, ['A', 'C', 'D']] = pd.cut(df.loc[:, ['A', 'C', 'D']].stack(),
                                    (-np.inf, 2.99, 5, np.inf),
                                    labels=('neg', 'neut', 'pos')
                                    ).unstack()
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>       A     B     C     D     E
> 0  neut  3.50  neut  neut  3.00
> 1  neut  5.25  neut   pos  2.00
> 2  neut  4.00  neut  neut  5.50
> 3   neg  4.00  neut  neut  2.75
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias FJ! Descubrí `cut`, `stack` y`unstack` en la doc. ¿Podría decirme qué hace cada una de las líneas en combinación? Además, ¿cómo adaptarse al caso en que se quiere modificar sólo algunas columnas?

Comment: He editado la pregunta con una posible solución para el caso de querer modificar solo algunas columnas del DataFrame. En cuanto a lo de cut / stack / unstack  a ver si mañana tengo algo más de tiempo y lo edito con ejemplos paso a paso para que se entienda que hace cada uno de ellos.